# (Full-Text Search) Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, full-text-search

I there, I would be glad with a little bit of help on this. I'm trying to build a full-text search function in Laravel, and I almost succeed in my objective, but suddenly I stopped to be able to retrieve the requested objects from the database. At some point something got broke on the code without my understanding of what or when exactly. I had just succeeded to be able to retrieve the queried pages by language, started to work on something else, and then "BAM!".. I couldn't get anything other than a "trying to get property of non-object" error. Does anyone spot anything wrong in my logic, or any typo? I've tried to get around this with several mutation of the code, trying to spot any silly mistake, but had no luck yet...

Routes.php

```
Route::get('{lang}/search/{query}', 'HomeController@searchPages');
```

HomeController.php

```
public function searchPages($lang, $query) {

    $cPage = Page::join('langs', 'langs.id', '=', 'pages.lang_parent_id')
                ->where('slug', '=', 'search')
                ->where('code', '=', $lang)
                ->select('langs.*', 'pages.*')
                ->first(array('langs.id AS language_ID'));

    $searchResults = Search::acme($query, $lang);

    return View::make('search.search')
    ->with('cPage', $cPage)
    ->with('searchResults', $searchResults);
}
```

models/Page.php

```
class Page extends Eloquent {

    public function scopeSearch($query, $search) 
    {
        return $query->where(function($query) use ($search) 
        {
            $query->where('title','LIKE', "%$search%")
                  ->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', "%$search%");
        });
    }
}
```

Acme/Facades/Search.php

```
namespace Acme\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Search extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() 
    {
        return 'search';
    }
}
```

Acme/Search/SearchServiceProvider.php

```
namespace Acme\Search;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SearchServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('search', 'Acme\Search\Search');
    }
}
```

Acme/Search/Search.php

```
namespace Acme\Search;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Page;

class Search {

    public function pages($search) 
    {
        return Page::search($search)->get();
    }

    public function acme($query, $lang) 
    {
        return new Collection(Page::join('langs', 'langs.id', '=', 'pages.lang_parent_id')
        ->where('code', '=', $lang)
        ->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
        ->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
        ->get()
        ->toArray());
    }
}
```

views/search/search.blade.php

```
echo $searchResults;

@foreach($searchResults as $searchResult)   

        <div class="search-result-container col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2">
                <a href="/{{ $cPage['code'] }}/{{ $searchResult['slug'] }}">
                    <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('{{ $searchResult['image'] }}');"> 
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-10 search-result-body">
                    <?php
                        $sr = HTML::decode($searchResult['body']) ;

                        $dom = new DOMDocument();
                        $dom->loadHTML($sr);
                        $node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
                        $sr_t = $node->nodeValue;
                        $sr_text = HTML::decode(str_limit($sr_t, 150, "..."));

                        $titles = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h1')->item(0);
                        $sr_title = $titles->nodeValue;

                        $title = HTML::decode(str_limit($sr_title, 150, "..."));
                    ?>

                <h3 class="search-result-title">
                    <a href="/{{ $searchResult['code'] }}/{{ $searchResult['slug'] }}">
                        {{ $searchResult['title'] }}
                    </a>
                </h3>
                <p>
                    <?php echo $sr_text; ?>             
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

—---Error----

Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Users/.../app/views/search/search.blade.php)

Open: /Users/.../bootstrap/compiled.php

(Line 9812)
     {
     $obLevel = ob_get_level();
     ob_start();
     extract($__data);
     try {
         include $__path;
     } catch (\Exception $e) {
         **$this->handleViewException($e, $obLevel);**
     }
     return ltrim(ob_get_clean());

Comment: Which line is it saying has the error?

Comment: I just added the error to my question. It doesn't say much to me.

Comment: The view has only that one line of code?  Try dd($searchResults) and what do you get.

Comment: Hi Joey. trying your code I can actually retrieve an object... object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#220 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(6) { [0]=> array(19) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1"... Does this means the problem is somewhere in the view code after this line?

Comment: Joey. Just added my code that should output the results in the view.

Comment: Where is $cPage being passed to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more tryings, I finally got this working by switching the order on the conditions of the Collection's query. The condition for the 'code' should be after the 'title' and 'body', like this:

```
public function marave($search, $lang) 
{
    return new Collection(Page::join('langs', 'langs.id', '=', 'pages.lang_parent_id')
        ->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->where('code', '=', $lang)
        ->get()
        ->toArray());
}
```

It would be nice if someone could explain me why this happens ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change.

```
//$searchResult->code to
$searchResult['code']
```

Comment: Hi Brian, I just added the code for the variable $cPage in the HomeController. It's being passed there. And I changed both $cPage->code and $searchResult->code to $cPage['code'] and $searchResult['code'], respectively without getting any effect...